# Return rows in text file

Tags: python, python-3.x, reactjs, pandas, flask

On the front end (React), the user uploads the text files and sends it to the backend (Flask) through a POST request.
I grab the file through  `file = request.files['file']`.
Now sometimes the text file could have several rows of information that wouldn't be considered column headings. For instance, it could look like:

```
2020-06-30
Users's name
Company

column1 name   column2 name   column3 name
data           data           data
data           data           data
```

Now if I use pandas I run this code:

```
import pandas as pd

read_file = pd.read_csv(file, delimiter="\t", error_bad_lines=False, header=None, nrows=50)
```

It will return the first 3 rows of the text file and skip the rest with the error: `expected 1 fields, saw 3`.

I need to return the first 50 rows as it appears in the text file. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

something like:

`df = pd.read_csv(fname, skiprows=4, **all_your_kwargs)`

Comment: The problem with skiprows is that it could always vary depending on the data being given. Sometimes there will be nothing to skip and it could go right into the column headers and data. Sometimes the column header starts deeper down the file.

Comment: write a function to calculate how many rows to skip by inspecting the data

Comment: couldn't you just find the first line that has a tab?

Comment: Hello! While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: thanks @Brian that is helpful feedback. in this case i thought `skiprows` was self-evident and i'm not sure what i could even write to clarify it.

Answer (score 0):

an example of reading rows is this:

```
file = open("test_file.txt", 'r')

for position, line in enumerate(file):
    if position in range(0, 50):
        print(line)
```

I don't know panda well enough to implement this into your code but you should be able to copy this into your code.

Comment: Thank you. But I get this error: TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not FileStorage 
Because the line file=request.files['file'] is actually an instance from FileStorage (flask/werkzeug).

Comment: This will only get the 0 and 49th line because 1 through 48 are not in `lines_to_read`. That should be `range(0,50)`

Comment: It's still wrong. It needs to be `range(0, 50)`. Using `range(0, 49)` will only count to 48. The second number in `range` needs to be 1 more than the number you want to stop on.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I had to do to return the whole text files without ignoring the non-header rows

```
file = request.files['file']
file_decoded = file.read().decode('utf-8')
file_data = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(file_decoded), error_bad_lines=False,
    delimiter='\n', header=None, nrows=50)
```

then to send to the front-end:

```
jsonized = file_data.to_json(orient='values')
#to_json is a pandas function
```

the json now looks like this on the front-end:

```
[
  ["2020-06-30"],
  ["user's name"],
  ["company"],
  ["column1 name   column2 name   column3 name"],
  ["data  data  data"]
]
```

i'm going to continue to play with the format of the json through `orient`